# No Canvas.ZIndex or SetZIndex() property on WPF Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas

I'm trying to change the Z order of components on my WPF canvas, but it doesn't seem to exist as a XAML property or method in the code behind.

Here's my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FrontendUI.Controls.RadialTracker"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FrontendUI.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="500">
<Grid >
    <Canvas x:Name="TrackerCanvas">
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

At first I was trying to do this programmatically:

[image]

Then I tried adding a Path using XAML and setting the Canvas.ZIndex, which also didn't exist. There was the Panel.ZIndex though, but I'm assuming this is referring to something higher in the UI (the grid, or User control itself?)

[image]

Not sure how to proceed. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Canvas inherits from Panel. Panel.SetZIndex() is a static method and Panel.ZIndex is an attached property that is why you are not seeing it in the xaml.

**To set ZIndex for child components in xaml.**

```
<Canvas >
        <Button Content="Button" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
</Canvas>
```

**To set Zindex for child components in code behind.**

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(control, index);
```

> **You said** "There was the Panel.ZIndex though, but I'm assuming this is referring
>   to something higher in the UI (the grid, or User control itself?)"

Your Assumption is wrong. To achieve your requirement you need to set the Panel.ZIndex

> **You asked** : But they all use Canvas.ZIndex, Does anyone know why this is happening?

Because ZIndex is an attached property (and not a regular dependency property).

Comment: Its static! God, why didn't I notice that. Thank you.